# Stripping spatial reference from raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, coordinates

I am creating an exercise for remote sensing students and would like to take an existing raster and remove the spatial reference from the file so that the students can practice using another image to orthorectify the first. I am using ArcGIS 10.

Any hints?

Comment: It depends on the file format of your image. Which files do you have (.tif .prj .tfw .aux.xml ...)?

Comment: It is a .tif file with an .aux.xml and .ovr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is to just delete the files that supply the spatial information related to the raster.  If the image is stored as a tiff or you can just open up the folder it's stored in and delete all the files except the actual image.  Then give that file to the students.

Looking at the image below, you would delete everything except the highlighted file, then distribute that.

[image]

I'm not certain how this would work with other raster formats that encapsulate the spatial information but you could always just export them to a tiff and then use this technique.

Comment: What about tiffs that store georeferencing information in [GeoTiff](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) tags in the actual tiff file, not in an external header file...?

Comment: I'm facing same problem but didn't found an ArcGIS solution. Is there any way to completely remove spatial references as well as extent coordinates from a GeoTiff?

Answer (score 7):

Another way that will completely strip any internal GeoTiff tags is by using the GDAL [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) utility to convert the tif to a baseline tiff.

```
gdal_translate -co PROFILE=BASELINE in.tif out.tif
```

I realise you are using ArcGIS, so do I, but I have found [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) to be another valuable tool in my geospatial software toolbox. Precompiled GDAL binaries can be downloaded from the [GISInternals](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) website.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the coordinate system as **unknown** by using the Define Projection tool. At the point of selecting the spatial reference, click on the little down arrow as indicated below and select *clear*.

[image: Define Projection Tool]

Comment: This will remove only the header, but not the coordinates themselves. Thus, you can try to find the correct coordinate system using the search method (brute force).