# Erasing spatial reference from GeoTIFF raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I am wondering is there any way to remove spatial reference from Geotif file, a composite of WorldView-3 8 bands in single Geotif file on projected coordinate system i.e. UTM. I guess spatial reference information is embedded within this single file. As such, there are no associated files supplying spatial information.

I have used gdal translate utility available in QGIS recommended in the [link on GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62170/stripping-spatial-reference-from-raster-using-arcgis-desktop?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but it didn't worked. No baseline .tif file is exported by the utility. The output raster file is again a composite .tif file retaining its previous spatial references, specially, earlier coordinates which are visible on taskbar in ArcMap. No associated tif files (World file) could be seen in destination folder to remove spatial references from there. What might be the solution to get desirable output?

Comment: You could simply save it in a different format and delete the correspondig world file.

Comment: But most other formats have.

Comment: @Erik please guide me further, I have saved it in different file format like .img, jpg but encountered same problem. How would I get rid of spatial information contained in the image? I am intending to completely remove it to get flat image for further processing.

Comment: There is already a resolution linked. What's wrong with that one?

Comment: The solutions advised in the referred post are not working for me. I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: The suggested GDAL utility (translate) again produces single tif file with spatial information contained within it.

Comment: Similar discussion and solutions over on geonet [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/16058).

Comment: @Hornbydd please note that the refereed discussion is limited to clearing coordinate system information, the resultant raster contains native coordinates when we add and hover mouse pointer over it. On the contrary, I am intending to produce raster without any georeference information, particularly, its coordinates.  I have modified my question accordingly.

Comment: Are you saying for example you have a grid and its bottom\left corner is at 10,10, you wand it to be 0,0? Why not *shift* the grid -10,-10?

Comment: Yes, it can be shifted as suggested. Alternatively, can I erase its spatial information across the grid as well?