# Removing georeferencing from DEM using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dem, georeferencing

I am creating an assignment for students to demonstrate different visualizations of LiDAR-derived DEMs. However, because the DEM is currently unpublished and contains archaeological features, I want to remove or change the spatial reference information so that it cannot be used to locate the site.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.6.

Comment: You may want the correct map units and perhaps statistics to make different visualizations from a DEM.  So you could deliberately do the classic error that new users often make which is to use the Project Definition tool instead of the Reproject tool to change the CRS to something it isn't such as a different UTM zone or State Plane system that uses the same map units.  If you think one of them is clever enough to reverse that you could simply open the world file or xml in notepad and change the location of the top left corner to an arbitrary point.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62170/stripping-spatial-reference-from-raster-using-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your DEM, look at the file location in File Explorer. You may see a world file, maybe some other things too. Delete everything except the .dem file. I believe the spatial reference information is stored in additional files, similar to shapefiles.

Comment: If DEM is a GeoTIFF then the georeferencing info is also stored inside the TIFF file and deleting the additional files does not help.

Comment: Correct. Edited my answer.